# Can I Apply for patent for this?

Tags: software

I've implemented a new way of sharing files upto 1GB with friends, in real-time. Can patents be applied to this?

If yes, I'm from India, and I'm a student, 14yr old, and I want to apply for a patent regarding the file sharing. What's the best and cheapest way of applying a patent in India.

Also, will that patent be a patent outside India ?

My Website where I've implemented the file sharing is http://nettpals.in

Any ideas ?

Comment: I went through your site but didn't find that information which mean to be patent but nice try in small age you done a good work.Quick feedback is what you done new always mention in your site and how you done this.

Comment: Patents are geographical in nature. An India patent would only be valid for India, but it would prevent any  overseas company to do business in India for the same patented technology.

Answer (score 1):

As for the Indian Patent,  Section 3 in [MANUAL OF PATENT PRACTICE AND PROCEDURE](http://ipindia.nic.in/ipr/patent/Patent_Manual_Feedback/WO_Ga_34_China.pdf) describes what are not inventions:
And 3 (k) specifically mention that:

> a mathematical or business method or a computer program per se or 
>   algorithms;

So keeping this in mind you should try to know if your invention is merely a method or computer program.

However, I have seen many patents which are softwares that run with a dedicated hardware. So software with a hardware (with some meaningful purpose), can be filed (or is worth filing).

Also before you think you have a novel way of sharing the files, you should get it searched on known data bases (both free and paid) by professionals or you can do it your self (at least on free databases).